# Ensure super.onDestroy() in derived component

Tags: angular, typescript, inheritance

I have bunch of components with very similar lifecycle logic, so I have created my base component, that implements `OnDestroy`

```
abstract class BaseComponent implements OnDestroy {
   subscriptions = new Array<Subscription>();
   get model() { return … }

   ngOnDestroy() {
      for (let s of subscriptions) s.unsubscribe();
   }
}
```

however, when a developers writes custom onOnDestroy method in concrete Component that extends `ComponentBase`, he has no way to know he need to call `super.ngOnDestroy()`;

Is there some (typescript) way to ensure warning? Or pattern other that component inheritance?
maybe a unit test that would test `ngOnDestroy` on all components that extends `BaseComponent`?

**EDIT**
I came to conslusion, that the `BaseComponent` with array of subscriptions above is a common antipattern and should be avoided. Ideally using auto unsubscribing observables.

See this takeUntil(destroy$) pattern:

```
class MyComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {    
    destroy$ = new Subject();    
  
    constructor(http: HttpService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        http.get(...).pipe(
          takeUntil(this.destroy$)
        ).subscribe(...);  
    }
    

    ngOnDestroy() {
      onDestroy$.onNext();
   }
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21388

Answer (score 7):

The simplest solution is to define a return type of `ngOnDestroy` that the child needs to return as well.

```js
class REQUIRED_SUPER {} //important to not export it, only we should be able to create it.

class Base implements OnDestroy {
    ngOnDestroy(): REQUIRED_SUPER {
        return new REQUIRED_SUPER;
    }
}
```

so, if your user doesn't return it as well, it means he didn't call your method.

```
export class Child extends Base implements OnDestroy {
    ngOnDestroy(): REQUIRED_SUPER {
    }
}
```

This leads to `TS2355: A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value.`

To solve it, your user needs to do it like this:

```
ngOnDestroy(): REQUIRED_SUPER {
    return super.ngOnDestroy();
}
```

or

```
ngOnDestroy(): REQUIRED_SUPER {
    const superCalled = super.ngOnDestroy();
    //to stuff
    return superCalled;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I know its late.. but for someone who needs it.!!!

```
export abstract class BaseClass implements OnDestroy {

ngOnDestroy(): void { }

constructor() {
    const refOnDestroy = this.ngOnDestroy;
    this.ngOnDestroy = () => {
        refOnDestroy();
       // perform unsubscriptions here
       // eg: for (let s of subscriptions) s.unsubscribe();
    };
 }
}
```

[Detailed description can be found here](https://stacksandfoundations.wordpress.com/2016/06/24/using-class-inheritance-to-hook-to-angular2-component-lifecycle/)

Comment: Thanks this is helpful! Had to add this: const refOnDestroy = this.ngOnDestroy.bind(this);

Comment: Didn't work on Angular 12, either with or without the `.bind(this)`.

Answer (score 3):

Most OOP languages dont offer the feature that you are looking for. Once a method is overriden by a child class, there is no way to enforce that the child invokes the parent implementation. In typescript there is [an open issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21388) discussing this feature.

A different approach would be to mark the implementation of ngOnDestroy on the base class as *final*, and give base classes a hook-up method to allow them to delegate tear-down logic. For example:

```js
abstract class BaseComponent implements OnDestroy {
   readonly subscriptions = new Array<Subscription>();
   get model() { return … }

   ngOnDestroy() {
      for (let s of subscriptions) s.unsubscribe();
      this.destroyHook();
   }

   // depending on your needs, you might want to have a default NOOP implementation
   // and allow child classes to override it. That way you wont need to spread NOOP 
   // implementations all over your code
   abstract protected destroyHook(): void;
}


class ChildClass extends BaseComponent {
   protected destroyHook(){//NOOP}
}
```

Saddly, [ts doesnt support an equivalent of the *final* logic ATM](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8306).

Another point of interest is the fact that this issue of yours arises from how you are planing to manage subscriptions on component instances. There are indeed better ways to do this, one of them being taking element from source observables *until* the component is destroyed. Something like:

```
readonly observable$: Observable<string> = ....;
ngOnInit(){
   observable$.pipe(takeUntil(/*this instance is destroyed*/)).subscribe(...)
}
```

This can easily be archived with libraries like [this](https://github.com/NetanelBasal/ngx-take-until-destroy)

Comment: You are right, this is likely the developers knowledge to know which kind of subscription needed to be unsubscribed .

And the use of destroy$ is smart :)

Comment: @Jota/Toledo: `Most OOP languages don't offer the feature`, because the problem doesn't exist there :) You usually have to use `override` keyword explicitly and there is no way of overriding a class member accidentally.

ECMAScript really sucks in this. Imagine that at some point you would add another hook to `BaseComponent`. It would be immediately overridden in all derived components that already have the hook.


This is BTW the reason why the `ngx-take-until-destroy` also requires ngOnDestroy even if empty, which is really weird.

Answer (score -1):

You could ensure that developers never write a `subscribe` in the components, that would avoid the need to unsubscribe.

This means you would use reactive programming to its full extent, with rxjs operators and async pipes.

You could also use a custom class decorator that tests all class members and see if they are instances of subscriptions.

You could finally use a custom rxjs operator that unsubscribes once your component is getting destroyed.

They are several options available, but I would recommend using the first one, as it makes your code cleaner and read for onPush change detection strategy.